# How to simplify Drupal Commerce checkout process

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

By default when we are at the cart page and click the button "Checkout", we are redirected to the "Order information" page, then we click "Continue to review" and we are redirected to the "Review" page and then we can click the last button to complete the process and we are redirected to the "Complete" page.

Is it possible and how to simplify the process so that if we click "Checkout" we are redirected to the "Complete" page with automatic choosing only one payment method by default?

I don't see the answer in their docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the answer is simple: to disable unnecessary panes in the default checkout flow